# Flutter Firestore query and document fields comparison

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query my firestore db but there's something not working fine:

```
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: matches
          .where('name',
              isEqualTo: name) // filtro in base al campo sport
          .where('day', isGreaterThan: newDate)
          .where('num_subscribed', isEqualTo: 'num_players')
          .orderBy('day')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView.builder(............
```

if I remove the line

```
.where('num_subscribed', isEqualTo: 'num_players')
```

the listview is building fine, but if I add that line, the result is empty.

Just to be sure, I tried to read the 2 fields one by one and they are read fine, only the comparison between the 2 of them is not working.

How can I query the db with the comparison between 2 fields of a document?

Comment: In your code above, it will produce query where value of num_subscribed = num_players. Like, num_players as String as it is.

Comment: but num_players is a number in firestore. will it be treated as string here?

Comment: Yes, it is treated as String. So you should make an Integer parameter of num_players   and then use it here like, `.where('num_subscribed', isEqualTo: num_players)`

Comment: this is good to know, thanks. But how can I keep an updated value of num_players outside the streambuilder? his value can change over time, so I guess it should be another stream as well

Comment: For safety reason, it is best to make another stream of num_players.